# How long must EDI files be archived for before purging them

Tags: archive, edi, standards-compliance, purge, edifact

I am looking to understand the rules behind purging EDI data from trading partners. I am lead to believe there is rules for the amount of time data must be archived for dependent on the country.

Is there set rules for how long a company must archive EDI files for before purging the files?

Comment: the rules for EDI documents are the same as for regular financial documents of the same type. If you have to keep invoices archived for 10 years, you have to keep electronic invoices archived for 10 years. Most document types don't require archival at all, it's mostly the ones your tax collectors are worried about. But if you for instance are required to keep all your communication archived for a given timeframe, that will count for EDI messages as well.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to provide that explanation. So I should be mostly concerned about the purging of our invoice documents?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It is based on the rules defined by your country. We had a customer where they had to keep the data for 7 years. We use